# Glassfish throwing Status 500 after deploying REST Web Service on JDK 8

Tags: java, linux, web-services, rest, glassfish

I´ve been building a REST Webservice on my local machine (MacOSX 10.10) and Glassfish 4. On my Mac I have Java Version 7. 
The Webservice was running fine till I deployed it on a Glassfish Server on a Linux machine which has also Glassfish 4 but JDK 1.8.

Source Code:

Sample Resource:

```
@Path("articles")
public class ArticleResource {
ArticleService service;

public ArticleResource(){
    service = (ArticleServiceImpl) SparWebServiceFactory.getService("art");
}

@GET
@Produces("text/plain")
public String getArticles() throws Exception {
    List<ARA1> articles = null;

    try {
        articles = service.getAllArticels();
    }
    catch(SQLException ex){
        throw new WebApplicationException(ex.getMessage());
    }

    if(articles == null){
        throw new WebApplicationException(404);
    }

    JSONArray allArticles = new JSONArray();
    for(ARA1 art : articles){
        JSONObject ara1 = new JSONObject();
        ara1.put("ArtNr", art.getArtNr());
        ara1.put("ArtKName", art.getArtKName());
        ara1.put("ArtName1", art.getArtName1());
        ara1.put("ArtName2", art.getArtName2());
        ara1.put("ArtName3", art.getArtName3());
        ara1.put("ArtTyp", art.getArtTyp());

        JSONObject anf = new JSONObject();
        anf.put("Betrieb", art.getAnforderung().getBetrieb());

        /*
            Berechnen ob der Artikel noch oder schon verkauft werden darf
        */
        Date vkListVon = art.getAnforderung().getVkListVon();
        Date vkListBis = art.getAnforderung().getVkListBis();

        if(vkListVon.after(new Date()) || vkListBis.before(new Date())){
            continue;
        }

        anf.put("VKListVon", vkListVon);
        anf.put("VKListBis", vkListBis);
        ara1.put("ANF1", anf);

        JSONObject fvp = new JSONObject();
        fvp.put("VPID", art.getVpid().getVpid());
        fvp.put("Fil", art.getVpid().getFil());
        fvp.put("FromDate", art.getVpid().getFromDate().toString());
        fvp.put("ToDate", art.getVpid().getToDate().toString());
        fvp.put("VkPreis", art.getVpid().getVkPreis());
        ara1.put("FVP", fvp);

        allArticles.add(ara1);
    }

    return allArticles.toString();
}
```

I´m creating my REST service with Jersey 2.0.
What could be the problem if first I´m running on JDK 1.7 and on the linux machine on JDK 1.8?

I´m thankful for your answers.
Alex

Comment: So where is the error message/stacktrace?

Comment: so you are building you app on Mac and then deploying it to linux ? can you try to build your app on Mac to see if you get any build errors ?

Comment: Yeah the problem is also the stacktrace. It just says Error 500 in the browser. Glassfish has no errors in the log. 

Im building my webservice on my mac and then I put it on my linux machine and deploy it in the Glassfish.